# How can I find the first word in a vector of strings that matches a user given prefix?

Tags: c++, string, vector

Let's say I have a sorted vector of strings:

```
std::vector<std::string> Dictionary
Dictionary.push_back("ant");
Dictionary.push_back("anti-matter");
Dictionary.push_back("matter");
Dictionary.push_back("mate");
Dictionary.push_back("animate");
Dictionary.push_back("animal");
std::sort(Dictionary.begin(), Dictionary.end());
```

I want to find the first word in the vector that matches a prefix, but every example I found use a hard coded string as prefix. For example, I can define a boolean unary function for finding the "an" prefix:

```
bool find_prefix(std::string &S) {
    return S.compare(0, 2, "an");
}
```

and use it as the predicate of the `std::find_if()` function to find an iterator to the first match. But how can I search for user given string as a prefix? Is it possible to use binary predicates in some way? Or build a "pseudo-unary" predicate that depends on a variable and a parameter?

Or, is there any other container and methods that I should use in this problem?

I know that there are much more efficient and elegant structures to store a dictionary for prefix search, but I'm a beginner self-learning programming, so first I'd like to learn how to use the standard containers before adventuring in more complex structures.

Comment: `std::set` saves you the trouble of sorting, and you get to ensure each word only appears once. C++20 will make this trivial with the member function `starts_with()`. Until then, the `find()` and `compare()` functions in tandem will get you there.

Comment: Also, if not `std::set`, calling `std::sort` on the vector, and then using `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` would be much faster than linear searching.  Imagine if there were thousands of strings.

Comment: I've first tried implementing the dictionary as a set, but I thought I couldn't use find_if() in this container.

Comment: `std::find_if` works fine with `std::set`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write `find_prefix` as a lambda. That lets you capture the string you want to search for, and use that for the comparison:

```
string word = ...  // the prefix you're looking for
auto result = std::find_if(Dictionary.begin(), Dictionary.end(), 
                           [&word](string const &S) {
                           return ! S.compare(0, word.length(), word);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I've trying using lambda functions, but I couldn't get past the first examples. So I can use any number of parameters between the brackets?

Comment: Yes, you can capture multiple variables.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sorting the vector, you should take advantage that the vector is sorted.

Rather than doing a linear search for a match, you can use [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) to put you close to, if not right on the entry that matches the prefix:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> Dictionary;
    Dictionary.push_back("ant");
    Dictionary.push_back("anti-matter");
    Dictionary.push_back("matter");
    Dictionary.push_back("mate");
    Dictionary.push_back("animate");
    Dictionary.push_back("animal");
    std::sort(Dictionary.begin(), Dictionary.end());
    
    std::vector<std::string> search_test = {"an", "b", "ma", "m", "x", "anti"};
    for (auto& s : search_test)
    {
        auto iter = std::lower_bound(Dictionary.begin(), Dictionary.end(), s);
    
        // see if the item returned actually is a match
        if ( iter->size() >= s.size() && iter->substr(0, s.size()) == s )
            std::cout << "The string \"" << s << "\" has a match on \"" << *iter << "\"\n";
        else
           std::cout << "no match for \"" << s << "\"\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The string "an" has a match on "animal"
no match for "b"
The string "ma" has a match on "mate"
The string "m" has a match on "mate"
no match for "x"
The string "anti" has a match on "anti-matter"
```

The test after the `lower_bound` is done to see if the string actually matches the one found by `lower_bound`.

Comment: I've known about the lower_bound() function, but i didn't thought of using it like this. In hindsight, as the strings compares using lexicographical order, it makes perfectly sense using it to search prefixes. Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't need such complex check, if vector is sorted, `lower_bound` would return either correct iterator or Dictionary.end(). So you need just compare iterators

Comment: No, you have to check.  The `lower_bound` returns the position in the sorted vector where the item would be inserted.  You're thinking of `std::binary_search`, which returns `true` or `false`.  [See this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d5381f408a42dfa).  The `"b"` doesn't match, but the iterator returned `"mate"`.